# Site appearing on Google SERP in spite of proper robots.txt configuration

Tags: javascript, html, seo, google-search, robots.txt

I have a ExpressJS web application, that is used for internal purposes, that I don't want Google to index. So I have implemented the following route:

```
app.get('/robots.txt', function(req,res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.send('User-agent: *\nDisallow: /');
}
```

I verified that this was working fine, by hitting the URL and checking the response, which is

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

In spite of this, I can see the my page result on Google when I search for the site title. The app has been online for a year or so now, so it couldn't have been cached results. Is there any other possible reason why this is happening? Any methods to troubleshoot?

Comment: Don't these pages you don't want google to index have security?, if so google can't index secure pages, as in you have to log in.  `that is used for internal purposes`  to me that quote, would indeed tell me you need some sort of authentication.

Comment: Yes, they have OAuth2 authentication. The login page is the one that is indexed

Comment: If it's internal, and you want to force it to be internal.  You can check the IP address.  No matter what Meta Tags you place on your website, knowing that your page doesn't get indexed is never guaranteed.  Google might obey robots.txt & `meta name`, but there is not guarantee other indexing services would do the same.

Comment: `You can check the IP address` Could you explain this

Comment: The `req` object has access to the remote's IP address. `req.connection.remoteAddress`, please note if your running behind a proxy make sure your express app has the `trust proxy` enabled, otherwise you will get the proxy's IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54879/does-google-ignore-robots-txt

> Google will still see sites blocked by robots.txt, and may even list them in search results.
>
> This is especially the case when entire domains/subdomains are blocked. Google will list links to these along with the text A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more with a link to https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449 .

add a `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">` to your pages output.

**EDIT**
From the discission in the comments:

> If you allow a page with robots.txt but block it from being indexed using a meta tag, Googlebot will access the page, read the meta tag, and subsequently not index it.

So to prevent google crawling your site: use deny in robots.txt, no need for meta tags.
If there are external links pointing to your site: use allow in robots.txt, use noindex, nofollow on those pages that appear in google.

How to easely see which pages google has on you:

Use `site:stackoverflow.com` as search query, and google will list basically all pages of that website it has indexed.

To learn more about how google crawls your pages:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/4617736?hl=en&ref_topic=4589290

Also, remember, google isn't the only search engine. There's bing, yahoo, baidu and a plethora of other searchengines, and not all play nice with meta tags or robots.txt, some even pretend to be another search engine so their crawl doesn't get blocked.

Comment: Ah the robots meta was not set. I'll set that. Thanks for your answer. How much time according to your experience does it take for the index to update on Google?

Comment: depends how often you get crawled. if your site update often and has many external links pointing to you, within a day. if you are a hidden site from the web, up to a month or two.

Comment: This is a good solution, but I would like to add, if you add robots meta tags, you will also need to un-block the site in robots.txt. Otherwise, Google will never crawl the pages, and will therefore never see the robots meta tags.

Comment: @plasticinsect Do you mean to say that I should _remove_ my restrictions on robots.txt? Should I just let google in?

Comment: Never mind I found what you meant: `If you allow a page with robots.txt but block it from being indexed using a meta tag, Googlebot will access the page, read the meta tag, and subsequently not index it.`

Comment: @nikjohn That is correct. You can block with robots.txt, or you can block with robots.meta, but you can't do both at the same time.

Comment: @plasticinsect Could you add this as an answer? I think this is more accurate